# mySocketClient.waitingForResponse() or similar?

Tags: java, sockets, response

So.. i have a server socket, here:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5000);  

while(true){  
    Socket cliente = server.accept();  
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Converter(cliente));  
    thread.start();
```

My app converts a Word document (`.doc`) to a PDF. First my server receives a .doc, makes a conversion, after a response with .pdf archive.

How do I get the client that is waiting for a response?

Comment: Meaning what? The thread that is handling that client connection has a socket open to that client. What more do you want? Not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are creating one thread per each accepted socket (thus client). This `Converter` thread has access to client socket (every client has a different socket returned by `accept()`). Now the solution is quite simple:

```
public void run() {
    cliente.getInputStream();  //read .doc first
    //do the conversion to .pdf
    cliente.getOutputStream();  //send .pdf back
}
```

Answer (score 1):

get:

```
private void getDocArchive(){  

    try {  

        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();  
        BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(in, 1024);  

        byte[] b = new byte[1024];  
        int len = 0;  
        int bytcount = 1024;  

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("docs/atual.doc");  

        while ((len = buffer.read(b, 0, 1024)) != -1) {  
            bytcount = bytcount + 1024;  
            out.write(b, 0, len);  
        }  

        out.flush();  

        //out.close();  
        //buffer.close();  

    } catch (IOException e) {  
        System.out.println("Ocorreu um erro no recebimento do arquivo");  
    }  
}
```

response:

```
private void reponse() {  
    try {  
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();  
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pdf);  

        BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(in, 1024);  

        byte[] b = new byte[1024];  
        int len = 0;  
        int bytcount = 1024;  
        int i = 0;  

        while ((len = buffer.read(b, 0, 1024)) != -1) {  
            bytcount = bytcount + 1024;  
            out.write(b, 0, len);  
        }  

        out.flush();  
        out.close();  
        buffer.close();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
    }  
}
```

my client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  

    try {  

        Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);  

        OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();  
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\autistmo.docx");  

        BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(in, 1024);  

        byte[] b = new byte[1024];  
        int len = 0;  
        int bytcount = 1024;  

        while ((len = buffer.read(b, 0, 1024)) != -1) {  
            bytcount = bytcount + 1024;  
            out.write(b, 0, len);  
        }  

        // resposta  

        BufferedInputStream buffer2 = new BufferedInputStream(in, 1024);  
        FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream("docs/final.doc");  

        while ((len = buffer2.read(b, 0, 1024)) != -1) {  
            bytcount = bytcount + 1024;  
            out2.write(b, 0, len);  
        }  

        out2.close();  
        buffer2.close();  

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

run method:

```
@Override  
public void run() {  
    getDocArchive();  
    converter();  
    reponse();  
}
```

Comment: +1 for a very thorough sample!

Comment: `bytcount` should be initialized to zero, not 1024, and `bytcount = bytcount + 1024;` should be `bytcount = bytcount + len;` throughout.